# getelementbyid().onclick works for one button but doesn't work for another

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid, buttonclick

I have five buttons in my html page. I used to create four of them by javascript and one with html, but after various changes decided to create all of them with html. The problem is that previously all of my buttons worked just fine, but after the change the ones previously made by javascript don't work anymore. I use getElementById("").onclick = function() for all of the buttons, yet only one of them works. (I only made the functionality for one of the four buttons because I encountered this problem)

Here is the javascript for both of the buttons. button1 is the one that doesn't work, I even tried with only having console.log() inside the function, but it didn't do anything.

```
        document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(){var element = document.getElementById('presetPicker');element.value = this.value;providerManager.refreshProviders();};
        document.getElementById("DownloadXml").onclick = function (){createReport('http://192.168.0.101:8080/rest/v1/excel-reports/run/XLT_211607',verifyReport)};
```

Here is the html part of the page

```
<body>
    <div id="container1">
        <header>
            <img src="http://www.jamk.fi/globalassets/tietoa-jamkista--about-jamk/materiaalit-esitteet-asiakaslehdet-ja-logot/jamkin-logot/jamk_fi--tunnus/jamkfi_tunnus_sininen_suomi.png" alt="Jamk logo" style="width:50%;height:50%;margin-left:25%;"> 
        </header>
        <div id="container2">
            <div id="textContainer">
                <h2>Fosfaattifosfori PO4-P [mg/l]</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="Graafi"></div>
            <div class="input">
                <div id="buttonContainer1">
                    <ul id="buttonList" class="timeForm">
                        <input id="button1" type="button" class="buttonGroup1" value="Previous day"
                        ><input id="button2" type="button" class="buttonGroup1" value="Previous week"
                        ><input id="button3" type="button" class="buttonGroup1" value="Previous month"
                        ><input id="button4" type="button" class="buttonGroup1" value="Previous year">
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="buttonContainer2">
                    <div id="list">
                        <ul id="downloadList">
                        <input id="DownloadXml" type="button" value="Download" />
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="download_div">
                        <img id="loading_gif" src="/modules/dashboards/web/public/359.gif" alt="Loading" style="display:block;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <iframe id="download_frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="testi">
                <select id="presetPicker" class="testi" ></select>
            </div>
            <footer>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Many of the functions are missing..

Comment: Missing `;` after `verifyReport)`

Comment: My bad. The button with verifyReport works fine, but the one on top of it doesn't react at all when being pressed. I actually tested it with only this format: document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(){console.log('test')} but that didn't work either. So to make things clear, the problem is that the other button reacts when being pushed, but the other doesn't give any reaction at all

Answer (score 0):

By adding an option `<option value="Previous day">Previous day</option>` to the select, your code works again. So either that is the problem, or the function `providerManager.refreshProviders();`, which I can't check, is giving you issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide a jsFiddle with the example?
I think you are loading the script before the DOM elements are drawn.
Maybe a $(document).ready() should resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Looks like there was no problem with the code itself, but I was using Firefox Web console to debug, and for some reason it didn't register any console.log() commands. After debugging with Browser console I found the debug data.

Feeling quite ashamed now

EDIT: should I remove the question or let it stay here to remind every starting developer to doubt their debug tools?